# Can we please get a "reviewers" section on /users page?

Tags: feature-request

Currently, there's no way for us to see who reviews the most in a given community. To even count one person's number of reviews, we have to go their profile individually, go to the "Activity" tab, click "all actions", click "reviews", and then figure out `#-of-posts-per-page(20) * #-of-pages - 1 + #-of-reviews-on-last-page`.

It's be nice if we could easily see the count for each individual of the community in a public place - the /users page is perfect for this.

I think doing so would make users want to review more because it gamifies the site even more. There would be a public place for people to easily see how many reviews they have made and compare that to others.

If the reason not to include this feature is that it'd clutter the current bar, I honestly think this would be more helpful than the "editors" section and wouldn't mind it replacing it.

Can we please get a "reviewers" section?

A side note is that is may be nice to have a drop down or something to select a *specific* review section count page, i.e. Suggested Edits, Close Votes, etc.

Comment: "I think doing so would make users want to review more because it gamifies the site even more. " Ahh, but don't forget that *I think doing so would make users want to robo-review more because it gamifies the site even more.* How can we stop people from doing that?

Comment: @MARamezani It would put them under more publicly visible scrutiny. "How did they get so many reviews in a month?"

Comment: @Troyen That logic doesn't make much sense. It's easy to max out on reviews done the right way if enough time is invested, so there's no way we, based solely on the count, can know a person is robo-reviewing. It also implies that the people robo-reviewing care what others think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there's no way for us to see who reviews the most in a given community.

The top reviewers in every category are already shown on `{site}/review/{review-type}/stats`.

> I honestly think this would be more helpful than the "editors" section and wouldn't mind it replacing it.

Why would you think that someone who spent a few minutes cleaning a messy post deserves less recognition than someone who scanned a suggested edit for 5 seconds and clicked Approve?

It takes a lot more energy to edit 20 posts than to review 20 posts; indeed, one has to thoroughly review the content before even beginning to edit. Good active editors are few and they should be appreciated more, not less.

Comment: I honestly didn't know that stats tab had that functionality (I assumed it was personal stats). It'd be nice if we could sort it by week/month/quarter/year/all like we can on the `/users` page and browse through more users. I made a [separate feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254231/215485) for that