# Make Review Stats function like Users section, push up review stats as well

Tags: feature-request, review-stats

I just found out there is a `{site}/review/{review-type}/stats` page. This is great! It has some functionality that I was desiring.

However, I'd like it to be more useful. Could we please get it to work more like the [`/users`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) page but have the additional functionality of the existing stat table up top and the top reviewers for the day? That would include pagination to browse reviewers for the given category and allow sorting by day/week/month/quarter/year/all like we can on the `/users`.

Also, it'd be handy to switch between the stats page of review types more easily somehow - perhaps a drop down would work?